# How to make R's read_csv2() recognise the text characters properly

Tags: r, utf-8, character, readr

Trying to read a csv file using `read_csv2()` from `readr` package.

The problem is `read_csv2()` doesn't recognise the characters properly while R's default `read.csv2` successfully does.

For example:

the original value: `KOZYATAĞI`

how `read_csv2()` recognises: `KOZYATA<'d0'>I`

I have checked the help file and also tried below listed coding; however couldn't make it happen.

1st try: ended up with wrong characters

```
my_df <- read_csv2("my_path/my_file.csv")
```

2nd try: manually state the encoding.

```
my_df <- read_csv2("my_path/my_file.csv", locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))

Error: `col_names` must be TRUE, FALSE or a character vector
```

3rd try: additions to 2nd try because of the error message above.

```
my_df <- read_csv2("my_path/my_file.csv", locale(encoding = "UTF-8"), col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL)
```

This one doesn't give error but still doesn't recognise the characters properly.

How to do it? Let me know if any other info needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us a dput of the first few trouble line to try. Otherwise... i would also try other codesets... other utfs... sometimes ANSI works for some strange reason

Answer (score 8):

@Amit, thanks for your suggestion.

On the RStudio, I have selected *File\Save with Encoding...* to see some of the available encoding options.

On the popped up window at the top of the encoding list it shows the system default (which is CP1254 for my computer). Then passed it to the encoding parameter as below and it worked!

```
my_df <- read_csv2("my_path/my_file.csv", locale(encoding = "**CP1254**"), col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now on Rstudio, looks like the options like this, [R Studio Version 1.2.1335 on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRvWz.png)

then, this code works:

`read_csv("C:path/file.csv", locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),col_names = TRUE,col_types = NULL)`

And spanish special caracters loads correctly (accents and ñ).